# BLE Discovering Result different between Windows 10 and Android 6

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I'm today in front of a problem with bluetooth and web app.

**Introduction**

First, here is my goal:
I want to connect a KDC (barcode scanner) in a web application (which will be probably write in C#, ASP.Net Core and JS). You can find the model and characteristic of this scanner here : koamtac.com/wp-content/uploads/KDC300.pdf .
The goal of this project is to use this website mostly on tablet and mobile, and not to use scanner with windows (but we would like to be able to see the website in computer aswell)
Sadly, Koamtac gives a SDK for windows local applications, for Android applications, but not really for web applications...

**BLE tool**

With this objective in mind, i discovered BLE technologies and the new Web Bluetooth API powered by google : [Google Web Bluetooth API Implementations Status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md).
As you can see, we could use it with windows to discover devices but not to be connect with them. (But with android 6+, it is possible to do both).

This tool seems to be just in line with my project but currently i didn't knew really if my KDC could be use as a BLE device. I decided to make a simple web application where i could test if i saw (or not) the KDC device.

**Application**

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(
    {
        acceptAllDevices: true,
        optionalServices: ['battery_service']
    })
    .then(device => {
        console.log('> Found ' + device.name);
        console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
        return device.gatt.connect();
    })
```

I did it on a github rep to get the HTTPS protocol which is needed to empowered the Web Bluetooth API. You can see this app here : [My GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Rlamotte/Rlamotte.github.io)

Finally, i tried this application with 3 differents states:

1. With Windows 10, in local (using Chrome Dev Tool)
2. With Windows, connected to rlamotte.github.io
3. With Android 6+ on my smartphone, connected to rlamotte.github.io

Before giving my results, you can see every bluetooth device in range of windows/android on the picture named "*Device_In_Range_......*" in the Github Rep

**Results**

I had those results:

1. In local, KDC device is every time found (see *Request_Device_Result_Windows_Local*). I can't connect to it (see *KDC_connect_Windows*) because Windows is not able to connect to GATT.
2. In this page (see *Request_Device_Result_Windows*), KDC is found 10% of time, and it takes much time to get it (approx 1 min). As you can see, Request found Gwladys, and 81PRMX1.
3. (see *Request_Device_Result_Android*), KDC is never found, and the request found EST (a beacon) and JBL Flip 3 (a bluetooth speaker).

**Conclusion:**

As you can see, the result of request_device is not the same with windows 10 and android 6. But when we use the bluetooth manager of those device, we saw exactly the same devices (the sum of devices found by each request_device).

I'm new to Bluetooth API area and i don't know why Android doesn't show all bluetooth device with request_device.

**THANKS** for you help ;)

**EDIT #1**

It seems that KDC 300 doesn't support BLE. I'm currently searching a way to connect bluetooth classic device to web app. If anyone has an idea you can tell me. If i don't find any powerful way to solve it, i'm gonna try to make an hybrid app android/windows with xamarin to use native bluetooth connection.

Comment: From the pdf it seems it uses Bluetooth classic and not ble?

Comment: It seems you're right. I contact the support of Koamtac who said "BLE is currently not supported". Wrong way here for my project then. Do you know any other way to connect to a classic bluetooth device throw the web? Or should i do an hybrid (and local) app, for windows and android?